# Need help creating script to move files to specific folders

Tags: powershell, copy

All files in a folder have an `_` (underscore) in the file name. All files should be moved into subfolders, were the subfolder name is the portion of the file name before the underscore. If the subfolder doesn't exist, it should be created.

```
Examples:
abc_123 -> moved to folder 'abc'
def_123 -> moved to folder 'def'
def_456 -> moved to folder 'def'
g_11 -> moved to folder 'g'
```

Obviously this will use `Move-Item` but other than that I have no clue. Any help please?

Comment: Well, you got the `Move-Item` part correct, so, what else have you tried? We'd prefer to see what you've tried so far and where in the code it's failing so we can assist with that. Not write it all out for you(: I would suggest gathering the items first (`Get-ChildItem`), and using some logic to *split* (can use `-Split`, or `.Split()`) the name at the underscore, grabbing just the beginning and verifying if the folders exist already.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Get-ChildItem` to get all items from the root source directory
- Use `ForEach-Object` to iterate through the results
- The `BaseName` property on each object/item will give you the file
  name without the path or file extension interfering; then you can
  use `Split()` to obtain the part before the underscore
- Use `Test-Path` to check if the destination directory already exists
- Use `Move-Item` to move the file from the source to the destination
- If the destination directory does not exist, use `New-Item` with the
  `-ItemType "directory"` parameter to create it, then run `Move-Item`

```
[string]$rootSrc = "root-source"
[string]$rootDst = "root-destination"

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootSrc | ForEach-Object {
    [string]$leafDst = $_.BaseName.Split("_")[0]
    [string]$dst = "$rootDst\$leafDst"
    if (Test-Path -Path $dst) {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dst -Force
    }
    else {
        New-Item -Path $rootDst -Name $leafDst -ItemType "directory"
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dst -Force
    }
}
```